# Populate column on PRECEDING calculation in Teradata

Tags: teradata, operator-precedence

I have two fields – Date and `OPR_DIST` , I Need to compute `OPR_MILEAGE`

For `OPR_MILEAGE` – If `Null(?)` and `Zero` in `OPR_DIST` then `ZERO` for `OPR_MILEAGE`

If `OPR_DIST` is not zero (eg: `0.37`) , I check the Prev. record (here its 0) hence `OPR_MILAGE` corresponding to `0.37` is `0`

If `OPR_DIST` is not zero (eg: `0.46`) , I check the Prev. record (here its `0.37`, which is not zero) hence `OPR_MILAGE` corresponding to `0.46` is same as `OPR_DIST`  which is `0.46`

So at any point, if my preceding record is `zero`, My current values for `OPR_MILEAGE` is `zero`, else `OPR_DIST`. Version I am using is TD 13

```
DATE    OPR_DIST    OPR_MILEAGE
6/10/2016   ?       ?
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.37    0
6/10/2016   0.46    0.46
6/10/2016   0.47    0.47
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.32    0
6/10/2016   0.37    0.37
6/10/2016   0.47    0.47
6/10/2016   0.56    0.56
6/10/2016   0.32    0.32
6/10/2016   0.26    0.26
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.3     0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.36    0
6/10/2016   0.25    0.25
6/10/2016   0.25    0.25
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.46    0
6/10/2016   0.24    0.24
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0.33    0
6/10/2016   0       0
6/10/2016   0       0
```

I am new to TD. Any light on this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a column to determine the order (probably a timestamp), you simply need to check the previous row's value:

```
CASE WHEN MAX(OPR_DIST)
          OVER (ORDER BY ???    -- previous row 
                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) > 0
     THEN OPR_DIST
     ELSE 0
END
```